# Мета-теги в Bitrix

Tags: битрикс, seo

В Bitrix в админке устанавливаю мета-теги для разделов. Для главных разделов устанавливаются нормально, но у подразделов title и description не меняются, остаются теги родительского раздела.
Делаю вроде все как в инструкции, сначала установила для главного раздела, потом пытаюсь переопределить для подразделов, и кеш сбрасываю, как написано, но ничего не меняется.
Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Может я не правильно вас поняла, но предположу, что если вам необходимо задать теги для подразделов, то это можно сделать через кнопку "SEO", вкладка "Управление".

[image: где прописать мета-теги в битриксе]

Answer (score 1):

Метатеги битрикс - это отдельный модуль SEO, который позволяет задать и сгенерировать автоматически метатеги. Для вывода значений надо сделать правки в component_epilog.php шаблона, а также прописать параметры компонента.  Почитатйте здесь.
[http://phpjs.ru/2017/06/15/битрикс-метатеги-для-торговых-предло/](http://phpjs.ru/2017/06/15/%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE/)